# How would I convert HTML into text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, code-snippets

I would like to make it so that the children of any element with the "snippet" class are read as text instead of HTML. I am aware that to do this, I would need to change the `<` and `>` signs so that the HTML page reads them as text. I have been trying to do this but unfortunately, I only have:

```
function(){
$('.snippet') 
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to display the HTML of the `.snippet` elements as text (with the tag names)? I'm a little confused by your wording.

Comment: When you ask a question please specific, and give some example of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.text()` function which will remove HTML tags:

```
var text_only = $('.snippet').text();
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/meZjw/

Docs for `.text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text

**UPDATE**

Sime Vidas has a good point, you can iterate through the different `.snippet` elements changing their HTML structure one at a time:

```
$.each($('.snippet'), function (index, obj) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text());
});
```

Here is a demo using `$.each()`: http://jsfiddle.net/meZjw/1/

**UPDATE**

Aepheus has a good point, I don't know if this is what is being asked but you can make a function that will escape HTML entities like in other languages:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/meZjw/2/

**UPDATE**

You can also use `.text()` and `.html()` in the opposite order as my above example, to the effect of showing the HTML of an element as plain-text:

```
$.each($('.snippet'), function (index, obj) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.html());
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/meZjw/31/

Comment: If there is more than one "snippet" element on the page (which is likely), the `'.snippet'` selector alone won't suffice, since `.text()` returns the concatenated text-content of *all* matched elements.

Comment: Why is this getting voted up, best I can tell it does not answer the question. For "<p>test</p>" .text() will return "test", the desired return is "<p>test</p>". And the second half, how to display this on the page is not answered.

Comment: @aepheus Good point, I interpreted the question differently. The second **update** to my answer provides a way to escape HTML entities.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
$('.snippet').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).html());
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/RrUAA/1/

Comment: This is the most complete answer, and it covers copying the element itself as well. Good job.

Comment: Hey, what if I don't want to convert <br> into text? I just want br to break line instead of just printing it as text.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want your code to be shown?  http://jsfiddle.net/vVgvt/4/

```
$('.snippet').html().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.snippet').text($('.snippet').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/PHUt3/) is what I use:

```
<span class="snippet">Who me? Why thank you.</span>
<div id="show_text"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 (function($) {

  var data = $('.snippet').text(); // or how ever you collect the data Object

  $('div#show_text').append( decodeURIComponent(jQuery.param(data)) );

 // debug report:
  if($.browser.mozilla){ //If you talk the talk, then you should toSource()
     console.log(data.toSource());
  }else{
     console.log(data);
  }  
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

cut out the parts that you need.